# SaveFile Dialog for MVC in razor/bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Am using OpenXml to open, modify then save a docx document. The code (not shown) will open the document, modify and I can save it directly to a direct path.  But cannot find how to make the user Save File AS dialog work?   *The type or namespace name 'SaveFileDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
     Response.Clear();
             Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
             string fileNamewrite =(string) (Session["FileNameFromUser"]);
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",    String.Format("attachment; filename={0}",fileNameout));
             Response.BinaryWrite(mem.ToArray());
             Response.Flush();
             Response.End();
```

The SaveFileDialog is the kind of method I hoped to use but cannot find any such similar method.

Even tried to install a bootstrap dialog with nice graphics?  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals  this worked a few times, then after modifying to fit my code, button clicking did nothing.  i went back to the original and pasted in, saved, still does nothing anymore.

The controller has modified the byte array, so at the Response.Clear(); to the end, this part runs and saves the file, but it has to be a user dialog save file as interface that returns the literal string path from the user?

Is there a similar kind of method as SaveFileDialog for MVC the controller can see?

Edit:
The browser setting was preventing the dialog box, it would just save to the /Downloads folder without prompting.  the secret is in one of the response header or content settings where a browser will automatically generate the saveFileAs dialog.  In WinForms it was something that is done manually... This method works, although it may have redundancy:

```
    public FileContentResult GetFile(byte[] m)
    {
        string mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        string filenam = "output.docx";
        byte[] fileContent = null;
        fileContent = m; //["FileContent"];
        ///////////////////////////
        Response.Clear();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileNameout);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

        // string fileNamewrite = (string)(Session["FileNameFromUser"]);
        // Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileNameout));

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return File(fileContent, mimeType, filenam); //pass contents as bytes[] , your mimetype , and the file name save as.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SaveFileDialog is a windows native app thing and not a web app thing.

Simply put... you cannot force the user to see a Save Dialog as it depends on what browser and what settings they have in their browser for what they see.

`content-disposition` only suggests a default filename if the user chooses to save the file! The browser uses the `content-type` header to determine what to do.

Comment: Ok so then its simply any kind of a browser wide dialog, and then on the buttons just add in the code to do the save?  Its what i had started to do with bootstrap hoping to get a universal pc/tablet friendly dialog, then it just stopped working;  the goal is just to get the literal file path back to the mvc controller